# GParted hanged for hours on shrinking

Tags: partitioning, gparted, resize

GParted is stuck on the shrinking step for the last 25 hours trying to shrink my 442GB Windows 8 oartition to 426GB. This partition is on my SATA HDD and I aḿ only modifying the end of the partition in order to put my new Ubuntu after it.

Should I just keep waiting or is there anything else I can do to speed up or cancel (without data loss) the process?

**EDIT:**

Gparted is still running, here's the current state from `top`:

> 15773 - root - 20 - 0 - 454m - 25m - 19m - R - 1,7 - 0,2 - 44:14.40 gpartedbin

So it looks to me it's still doing something isn't it? What's worrying me (but I'm surely mistaken there) is that `glances` doesn't notice anything happening on the HDD (IN and OUT) and there are those `A_DENY` on the `gpartedbin` line for the columns IO_R and IO_W (respectively read and write I guess?).

Comment: Open the progress details and see what stage it is on.

Comment: @psusi as I said it's at the (actual) resizing (last) stage. That's  the `ntfsresize -P --force` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after waiting for almost 50 hours on this I just gave up and decided to **cancel the shrinking operation** even though that could have meant data loss.

Once the operation was cancelled GParted couldn't recognize properly the Windows 8 partition, so I tried to use GParted to recover it. Without success.
That's when I decided to go for PhotoRec and TestDisk and I was surprised when TestDisk couldn't detect any errors on my partitions (even with the deeper search feature) and even better than that I was able to see that all my files and folders where intact on my W8 partition!

That's when I decided to give it a go and reboot it, but unfortunately (and as expect I should say) my W8 mbr was broken, so I used my W7 recover disk (I upgraded from W7 to W8 via downloading from Microsoft) to boot and run from the command line tool `Bootrec.exe /fixmbr` and **voila**! All my data was still there and my W8 was repaired (first thing I did was running a check disk that found no error).

To get back onto the Ubuntu subject, I decided to shrink the W8 partition from Windows this time, so after a few defragmentation runs and use of [MyDefrag](http://mydefrag.com/) (to get the data at the beginning of my disk when possible) I was able to shrink my W8 partition enough to make space for my Ubuntu install.

To conclude I think that **in my case** GParted really was hanging (for nothing) as no data has been lost from my W8 partition, and althought that took me a few days to repair I feel lucky that cancelling the shrinking didn't do any damage for me.

What I do recommend though is that if you want to shrink your Windows partition before installing ubuntu (or any other OS) next to it, use the windows tool for that (`diskmgmt.msc`).

Answer (score 2):

A 25-hour resize operation is definitely on the long side, bordering on excessive. It's entirely possible that the program has hung, in which case you should be prepared to restore from backups. (You should ***ALWAYS*** back up important data before performing a partition resize operation.) OTOH, it's possible that your disk just has data laid out in a way that's causing GParted to work slowly. If that's the case, the program will eventually finish and everything will be OK. It's hard to tell which of these is the case. If disk activity has completely stopped, though, I'd favor the "hung" hypothesis. If disk activity is ongoing, it could be either situation. Likewise for CPU load. (Type `top` in a Terminal window to see a dynamically-updated list of the programs that are using the most CPU time.)

Unfortunately, there's really no way to stop an ongoing partition-resize operation in a safe way. If the program has hung, you'll have to either restore your data from backups or spend a lot of time (with [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) or something similar) and/or money (on a data-recovery specialist) recovering the data.

I recommend giving it another day or so. If it's still not finished by then, the odds of it ever completing are pretty low. There's no hard-and-fast cutoff point, though -- or if there is, I don't know what it is, and it would vary depending on disk size, disk speed, and other factors.

Comment: Thanks for your input but although I know I should've backed up the data before, I did not unfortunately (but the critical data aren't on this disk anyway, although I have a few files I would've have really backed up somewhere...) I'm going for the waiting solution atm and see what happens, but it's still looking the same (please look at my edit above).

Answer (score 0):

Just wait.  The delay is not that it's "hanging" but rather that it's doing work.

The system will test-run the shrinking/moving of the partition first.  That takes time.  When it actually resizes and moves the data, that also takes time.  As well, when do you this resize, Windows may actually yell at you.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so but that's the best way I thought to describe it, sorry for not being accurate enough. So when do you think the process will end? (I am resizing from my USB stick if that is relevant) Cheers

Comment: @Nicolas I don't have Windows 8, but the resize on a 900GB+ partition for Win7 I had took less than a minute, however, moving the partition on the disk to a different location so I could make space for Ubuntu took even longer, took about 4.5 hours to test move and then actually move (1hr for test move, 3.5 hours for the actual move).  If you power down the system, it'll break the partitions and you lose everything.  And you can't really speed it up either.

Comment: Still sounds like a lot less than me. And I already did a resizing for a previous Ubuntu partition on this drive and it took just a few minutes, so that's why I'm wondering why it's taking so long this time...

Comment: Are you moving the partition around on the drive?  If you do ctrl+alt+f1, are there any error messages being displayed in that window?  (Kernel level error messages sometimes get spit out to TTY1 accessible by ctrl+alt+f1)

Comment: Unfortunately I don see any message on any TTY. Iḿ just downsizing the W8 partition, not even moving its start, only freeing some space after it on the disk.

Comment: He's already done "just wait".  After 25 hours it's a lost cause.  Shrinking to the left without moving the start should only take a few minutes to an hour, depending on how much data is actually sitting in the end of the partition and thus has to be moved.  Even moving the whole partition wouldn't take more than a few hours.

Comment: I agree with psusi, after 25 hours it's a lost cause.  The problem is, if the partition isn't finished resizing, then the data could be lost.

Comment: ThomasW. and @psusi : So what do you guys sugest I should do? IF I cancel it, should I be able to retrieve my W8 partition as it was before or at least access to some file on it, or is it a lost cause? =/

Comment: If you cancel the operation, then the disk state will be whatever it is, and there's no way to predict what that might be. It's conceivable that the filesystem will be readable and fairly easily recovered; or it could be a complete mess, and require recovery with PhotoRec or similar programs, or even be completely unrecoverable. Nobody can say with certainty what you'll find if you're forced to abandon the operation.

Comment: Nicolas, Rod Smith has it right, if you cancel the operation, then the disk state will be whatever it is when you stop, it could be good and recoverable, or bad and needs work for recovery, or completely busted.  This is why you should always back up critical data before working on the disks.

Answer (score 0):

It truly can take very long. I am shrinking currently a 171GB partition down to 100 GB. After running over the whole night, it still is at 62% in *simulating*.